# Transform stock tablet firmware to Android TV

Tags: device-firmware

Is there any public guide for the subj?
I have arm SOC Rockchip and the Android 11 firmware from the manufacturer ([downloadable](https://github.com/radxa/manifests/releases/tag/Rock-android11-20211115_1851) from their's GIT).

I am able to unpack it through all stages:

1. single img
2. boot + update.img
3. uboot.img + boot.img + recovery.img + super.img + ...
4. super.img.raw
5. odm.img + product.img + system.img + system_ext.img + vendor.img
6. each img from (5) complete unpacked until files

And I am able to pack it in backward order to flash and boot.

Is there enough to obtain ATV versions (according to the arch) for some apk's (which is ?) and just replace them in the source filepaths ?

Is there are list of conflicts apk's which is required to be deleted in oneway (without replacement) ?

Is there some special tunings required for the configs (SELinux for example) ?

UART/TTL in my hands and I am ready to read boot stdout :)

Comment: I don't have answer, I asked. If the same apps behave different what's the point of replacing system apps? Must be some setting that tells the app it's tablet or tv. if your question is about replacing apps in system.img I can answer **how** to do it. but I don't know what apps or settings, so my answer can't provide solution for the exact question

Comment: @alecxs, because the System Apps do the difference I am asking for. Different voice search. Different Play Market. Different Launcher. Different Google Services. Lot of differents and special improvements.

Comment: Most likely Android TV apps share a large part with the apps from Android for phone/tablet but there is a significant part that may be different. Conditional compiling respectively different flavors of the same app allow to build similar but different apps. This is what I would do if I would develop a system like Android TV.

Comment: For reference a true ATV device would need to support: https://source.android.com/docs/devices/tv otherwise a Android media box (IPTV?) could be running something like Kodi on top on regular Android.

Comment: @Morrison Chang, KODI is a good platform and I am use it with a single and central database point on a number devices at home, but it does not provide benefit of clean TorrentTV experience (it does, but with ugly workarounds). Besides, a lot of IPTV providers (in my outside environment) has its own ATV apps for provide viewing for TV broadcasting. So, cable transport for ATV - is an option. Good option (I have a USB DVB-C dongle and effectively want to test for FTA channels!). But not absolutely required.